# How to get an android auto sdk for the head unit side?

Tags: sdk, android-auto

I want to develop an Android Auto Head unit, and I was wondering if anyone knew where I can get the SDK or some point of contact to discuss that with Google

Comment: did u managed to find ther SDK?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older post, but wanted to add in some information. There’s a difference between what us developers can build for Auto and what car manufacturers/partners can. 3rd party developers can build apps for Auto using either the public [media or messaging templates](https://developer.android.com/auto/), while car manufacturers on the other hand can draw elements directly on the screen and have full pixel control.

Car manufacturers can build custom apps that run on their head units by using the SDK. The SDK isn’t used to establishing and develop a head unit, but essentially gives access to creating the activities etc. that will appear on the head unit. The Android Auto app shuttles the callbacks and methods back and forth between the mobile device and the head unit. However, to answer the question more directly, yes you would certainly need to get in touch with Google to get your hands on the SDK and whatever requirements or guidelines there are to interact with the head unit, though you wouldn’t use the SDK alone to develop one.